# how to send attachment using sendmail

Tags: java, email

I am use this class to send mail it works but now i wants to add attachment how to add it please help if u can

```
public static void sendMail(String subject, String body, String toEmail, String ccEmail, String fromMail)
                throws IOException {
            Random generator = new Random();
            int r = Math.abs(generator.nextInt());

            body = body.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
            body = body.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
            body = body.replaceAll("&", "\\\\&");
            body = body.replaceAll("©", "\\\\&#169;");
            //body = body.replaceAll("> <", ">\\\n<");

            if(CommonUtils.emptyString(fromMail))
                fromMail = "No Reply <iotasol@pcc.com>";
            else
                fromMail = "No Reply <"+fromMail+">";

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    ApplicationProperties.MAIL_SENDER_SH_PATH, CommonUtils.getEmptyStringForNull(subject), CommonUtils.getEmptyStringForNull(body),
                    toEmail, ccEmail, String.valueOf(r), fromMail);
            processBuilder.start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as an idea if you need to send images: make it inline with base64.

Attachments depends on library used, mail server used and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
       MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       File file = new File("somefile.txt");
       if (file.exists()) {
           DataSource source = new FileDataSource("somefile.txt");
           messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
           messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
           multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code example, I can tell that you are using external *mail* program for sending emails. You create a **ProcessBuilder** and invoke an OS tool for sending emails.

I would not use this solution. First, it depends on the OS (on windows you don't have the mail command). Second, this is not efficient; since you create external process for this (imagine sending many emails).

Instead, try using existing **mail** solution in java (you will need: mail.jar and activation.jar). With it you can send emails directly from your application, not depending on external tool.

While with **mail** Java library you can do everything you want, you may also look at [Jodd Email](http://jodd.org/doc/email.html). This is a small, but convenient wrapper over java mail library, that can help you with sending emails and attachments. As you can see in section '*Email using fluent API*', you can do the following:

```
Email email = Email.create()
    .from("from@foo.org")
    .to("to@bar.com")
    .subject("test")
    .addText("Hello!")
    .addHtml(
        "<html><body><h1>Hey!</h1>" +
        "<img src='cid:c.png'><h2>Hay!</h2></body></html>")
    .embed(attachment().bytes(new File("d:\\c.png")))
    .attach(attachment().file("d:\\b.jpg"));
```

In this example you can see two ways how you can attach your files: *embedding* them so they appear in HTML content, or common *attaching*. Of course, you don't have to use fluent interface, its just one option with this library.